# Can out of memory in PHP unset static properties?

Tags: php, zend-framework

We have an application that is using Zend Framework 1.  We have a known bug that sometimes causes PHP to run out of memory when trying to use the Zend_Json encoder.

What brings me here though is something else, we are also seeing in our logs a php fatal for Zend_Session::writeClose().

```
Message: Access to undeclared static property: Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled
File: /usr/local/zend/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.10/library/Zend/Session.php
Line: 720
```

`public static $_unitTestEnabled = false;` is declared at the beginning of the class.

In writeClose is a simple check of:

```
if (self::$_unitTestEnabled) {
    return;
}
```

Can an out of memory condition unset static properties? I'm trying to determine if this fatal is related to the known out of memory condition or if something else is wrong.

Comment: It cannot unset them, but it can prevent them from being set. I don't think ZF has a method to try to free up memory by doing this.

Comment: That makes sense but I wonder why the fatal didn't happen when trying to set that property?

Comment: They look unrelated to me. Try increasing the memory using `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');` in your `index.php` file (right at the top) to see if you can shift that out of memory bit and see if the other issue disappears.

Comment: I mistakenly thought the errors were from the same request , first the Zend_Json OOM fatal, and then the another fatal when writeClose was called in the destructor.  But they were actually separate requests a few seconds apart.  My hunch is that the OOM condition is happening in different places, but I'm still not clear why it didn't error when trying to set the static property unless that wouldn't be a fatal.